# Get-Mailbox Permissions

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've been tasked with creating a script which will:

- Return all mailboxes within a certain OU
- Show all users who have access to each mailbox
- Show the primary SMTP address of each mailbox

I have managed to do the following which returns the Mailbox and it's Primary SMTP address:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU Goes Here" -ResultSize Unlimited |
             Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I have also created another script which returns all of the users within each mailbox:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU Goes Here"

foreach ($mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
        select identity, user |
        Format-Table -Wrap
}
```

However, I am struggling to be able to pipe both of these together to bring back the mailbox, users and SMTP address in the same output.

Comment: How do you intend to merge these. The results sets do not have a one to one relationship so what would some sample output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU Goes Here"

    foreach ($mailbox in $Mailboxes) {

    Get-MailboxPermission -identity $mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | select @{Label="Name";Expression= {$MailBox.DisplayName}},@{Label="Email";Expression= {$MailBox.PrimarySMTPAddress}},identity, user  | Format-Table -Wrap

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you want. You will have to decide how you want to parse the permissions.

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU Goes Here" -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    Select PrimarySmtpAddress,DisplayName,Identity | 
    % { 
        $MB=$_; 
        $Perm = $(Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $MB.identity -ResultSize Unlimited | select identity, user); 

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ DisplayName=$_.DisplayName; PrimarySmtpAddress=$_.primarySmtpAddress; Permissions=$perm } 
    }
```

You can for example pipe to another select to expand the property

```
| select * -ExpandProperty Permissions
```

This also will show all of the various built in accounts for Exchange which may create more noise than you want.